# angular HTML ts array include

Tags: html, arrays, angular, include

How can I write some thing like that?

type of elements

```
type = MyType; // is an Enum
myObj: MyObj | undefined =  undefined;
myObj.type: MyType;
```

Currently

```
*ngIf="type.first === myObj.type || type.second === myObj.type"
```

how I try to refactor it

```
*ngIf="[type.first, type.second].include(myObj?.type)"
```

why? it's easier to read

the Error I get

> Argument of type 'MyType | undefined' is not assignable to parameter
> of type 'MyType'.

How can I make the second way without needing to create new method?

ADD

how I currently fixed it

```
*ngIf="[type.first, type.second].include($any(myObj?.type))"
```

Comment: add the definitions for MyType and MyObj please

Comment: In the current example you did not use ? but in the refactored example you did. That's why myObj.type can be undefined. So you need to wrap it in an *ngIf="myObj.type" or provide a default value.

Comment: @CCBet it's a enum so, ... some thing like that enum Direction {
  Up = 1,
  Down,
  Left,
  Right,
}

Comment: @RamonSchmitt haaa so you mean that I should have put in my class MyObj the type to possible undefined? But why? because it's he's parent (myObj) that can be undefined not the type